# Finding the value of the supremum of a set

Tags: analysis

Consider the set $S = \{x \in \mathbb R: x < \frac2x\}$. Determine the value of $sup$ $S$ (if it exists).

Here is my attempt:
Firstly, $S = \{x \in \mathbb R: 0 < x < \sqrt 2$ $\lor$ $x < -\sqrt2 \}$.
Since $1 \in S$, $S \ne \emptyset$.
Also, $\forall x \in S$, $x < \sqrt2$ and so $S$ is bounded above.
By the least upper bound property of $\mathbb R$, $sup$ $S$ exists.
Suppose $\exists y \in \mathbb R: y < \sqrt2 \land y$ is an upper bound of $S$.
Since $1 \in S$, $1 \le y < \sqrt2 \Rightarrow y \in S$.
...

How do I show that $sup$ $S$ $= \sqrt 2$?

Comment: Mistake in finding $S$ Note that $-1\notin S$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, it is correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find $S$ the equation $x<\frac2{x}$ or equivalently $\frac{(x-\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2)}{x}<0$ must be solved.

This leads to $S=(-\infty,-\sqrt2)\cup(0,\sqrt2)$.

Here $\sqrt2$ is an upper bound of $S$ and proving that $\sup S=\sqrt2$ comes to showing that every $y<\sqrt2$ is *not* an upper bound of $S$. That means: showing that $y<s$ is true for some $s\in S$.

Comment: If I interpret that correctly, that means I have to show that the (real) interval $(0, \sqrt2)$ does not contain a maximum. Any ideas on how I could start?

Comment: Take some $y<\sqrt2$. Without loss of generality you can take $y$ positive. Then $s:=\frac12(y+\sqrt2)\in S$ with $y<s$.

Comment: Thanks! It always amazes me how mathematicians can come up with seemingly arbitrary numbers like $\frac12(y + \sqrt2)$ for use in proofs. I hope that one day I can finally write my own proofs without relying on others.

Comment: You are very welcome and good luck with your study. "Mathematical maturity" is gained mostly by endurance and building up routine. It requires time.

Answer (score -1):

You shall prove that the supremum is not greater nor less than $\sqrt 2$. ie by supposing so in both cases and getting a contradiction.